# ORACLE :Are grants removed when an object is dropped?

Tags: oracle, rename, sql-grant, ora-00942, sql-drop

I currently have 2 schemas, A and B.

B has a table, and A executes selects inserts and updates on it.

In our sql scripts, we have granted permissions to A so it can complete its tasks.

```
grant select on B.thetable to A
etc,etc
```

Now,  table 'thetable' is dropped and another table is renamed to B at least once a day.

```
rename someothertable to thetable
```

After doing this, we get an error when A executes a select on B.thetable.

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Is it possible that after executing the drop + rename operations, grants are lost as well?

Do we have to assign permissions once again ?

## update

someothertable has no grants.

## update2

The daily process that inserts data into 'thetable' executes a commit every N insertions, so were not able to execute any rollback. That's why we use 2 tables.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If your regular day-to-day processing involves dropping and recreating tables, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @Jeffrey Kemp: I see. Do you think that @Peter Lang's alternative is the way to go? Personally, i think its a good idea, but not a db guy myself.

Comment: If you're working with an existing solution (i.e. if you just have to live with dropping and recreating tables), then yes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, once you drop the table, the grant is also dropped.

You could try to create a `VIEW` selecting from `thetable` and granting `SELECT` on that.

Your strategy of dropping a table regularly does not sound quite right to me though. Why do you have to do this?

**EDIT**

There are better ways than dropping the table every day.

1. Add another column to `thetable` that states if the row is valid.
2. Put an index on that column (or extend your existing index that you use to select from that table).
3. Add another condition to your queries to only consider "valid" rows or create a view to handle that.
4. When importing data, set the new rows to "new". Once the import is done, you can delete all "valid" rows and set the "new" rows to "valid" in a single transaction.

If the import fails, you can just rollback your transaction.

Comment: Well, i have a process that inserts information into a table 'thetabletmp', and if the process ends OK, then this information is passed to 'thetable' (by dropping 'thetable' and renaming 'thetabletmp' to 'thetable'). If it does not end OK, then 'thetabletmp' is dropped, and 'thetable' contains the last valid run.

Comment: Since it sounds like your process is all-or-nothing, why not process directly into "thetable", and commit or rollback as appropriate?  

Alternatively, if using Partitioning, consider using the EXCHANGE PARTITION functionality, which is designed for swapping data in-and-out of tables.

Comment: @Peter Lang: The 'valid column' strategy cannot be applied. The process commits every N insertions, so any rollback would be partial.

Comment: @Tom: This strategy also works without rollback. When you know that inserting has failed and do want to keep the old records, just delete all "new" records instead of the "valid" ones.

Comment: @Peter Lang: I see, i'm just afraid that the delete will take too long (probably about 20 M records or more)

Comment: @Tom: You could try to partition your table by that column, then performance should not be a problem. You would certainly have to test it though.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the process that renames the table should also execute a procedure that does your grants for you? You could even get fancy and query the dictionary for existing grants and apply those to the renamed table.

Answer (score 0):

No :
"Oracle Database automatically transfers integrity constraints, indexes, and grants on the old object to the new object."
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9019.htm#SQLRF01608

You must have another problem

Comment: That would apply if `SELECT` from `someothertable` would have been granted, but as I understand the question, this is a new table. Only `thetable` had the grants, but it was dropped.

Comment: Exactly, someothertable has no grants.

Comment: Okay, misunderstood.
Indeed, Grants are object-based and not name-based, the view strategy is the good one ;)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use a temporary table for the work you're doing.  After all, it sounds like it is just the data is transitory, at least in that table, and you wouldn't keep having to reapply the grants each time you had a new set of data/create the new table